# How to stream video to a RTSP Url via python?

Tags: python, azure, video-streaming, streaming, rtsp

I am capturing frames from a RTSP url using opencv

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(input_rtsp_url)
```

Now I want to stream these captured frames to another RTSP Url "Output_rtsp_url". I will be performing YOLOv5s object detection on the frame and drawing bounding boxes on it before sending it to another RTSP url which is connected to Azure live stream media. However im not able to figure out how stream these frames back to Azure live stream media using the second RTSP url. Can anyone help me with a code on how to stream these frames to an RTSP url using python?

Let me know if any additional details are required!
Thanks in advance !

I have tried using FFMPEG, Gstream, PyCurl etc which I could gather from online resources and AI models. However none of them seem to work without giving a magnitude of errors. Im expecting a code that will send these frames to the output url as needed. Thankyou!

Comment: sample example stream video to a RTSP Url via [python](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-python/tree/main/Live) and for more details refer [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-python)

Answer (score 0):

The [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/) package and the cv2.VideoWriter class can be used to stream video to an RTSP URL. Here is an illustration of some sample code that shows how to grab frames from an RTSP URL, use YOLOv5 to do object identification, create bounding boxes on the frames, then stream the processed frames to another RTSP URL:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

- [Create an Azure Media Services live stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/live-event-wirecast-quickstart)
- [Live events and live outputs concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/live-event-concept)

[image]

**Sample Code :**

```py
import  cv2
input_rtsp_url = "rtmps://sampath234-sampath-usea.channel.media.azure.net:2935"
output_rtsp_url = "https://sampath-usea.streaming.media.azure.netmanifest.ism/manifest(format=m3u8-cmaf)"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(input_rtsp_url)
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
output_stream = cv2.VideoWriter(output_rtsp_url,  cv2.CAP_FFMPEG,  0,  fps,  (width,  height))
while  True:
ret,  frame = cap.read()
if  not  ret:
break
output_stream.write(frame)
cv2.imshow("Processed Frame",  frame)
if  cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
break
cap.release()

output_stream.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

- From this [Reference](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-python/blob/main/Live/Basic_Passthrough_Live_Event/basic_passthrough_live_event.py).

```py
input=LiveEventInput(

streaming_protocol=LiveEventInputProtocol.RTMP, 

access_control=live_event_input_access, 



access_token='9eb1f703b149417c8448771867f48501'

),

encoding=LiveEventEncoding(
encoding_type=LiveEventEncodingType.PASSTHROUGH_BASIC),
stream_options=[StreamOptionsFlag.LOW_LATENCY]

)

print("Creating the LiveEvent, please be patient as this can take time to complete async.")

print("Live Event creation is an async operation in Azure and timing can depend on resources available.")

print()
```

[image]

```py
# Create VideoWriter object for output RTSP stream fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"H264") output_stream = cv2.VideoWriter(output_rtsp_url, fourcc, fps, (width, height))
```

For more details of Refer this links:

- [media-servicesLive at main](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-python/tree/main/Live)
- [media-services samples for Media Services](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-python)

Comment: The player on the output link shows no output. I think sending frames this way isnt working.

Comment: For more details of Video stream Refer this [git](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-python/tree/main/Live)